# DirectoryServicesCOMException when clear AD Property (CountryCode)

Tags: active-directory, directoryentry

I try clear COUNTRYCODE property for ActiveDirectory using NET (DirectoryEntry, PrincipalContext)

```
public const String COUNTRYCODE = "countryCode";


    if (dEntry.Properties.Contains(property))
    {
        dEntry.Properties[property].Clear();
        dEntry.CommitChanges();
        dEntry.Close();
        return;
    }
```

The error:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException
>
> ExtendedError 8311
>
> ExtendedMessage: 00002077: SvcErr: DSID-031903C9, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

I try:

```
dEntry.Invoke("Remove", new object[] { property });
```

or

```
dEntry.Invoke("remove", new object[] { property });
```

I get the error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Nombre desconocido.
> (0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see `WILL_NOT_PERFORM`, it means you are trying to do something that is not allowed.

You cannot clear the `countryCode` attribute. It must have a value. You can set it to `0` if you'd like.

Comment: I can clear for **COUNTRY and COUNTRYNOTATION attributes**, for another attributes like `countryCode` is required set value to 0.